# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module HelloWorld.ko: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to learn linux and kernel development.

I am able to build the module but am unable to load it.

**HelloWorld.c**

```
/*  
 *  hello-1.c - The simplest kernel module.
 */
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");

    /* 
     * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded. 
     */
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

And here is my make file:

```
KERNEL_SOURCE := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

obj-m += HelloWorld.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

while doing insmod for loading the module permission is getting denied. I tried even doing it with root and also with modprobe, but no use.

I also tried [Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10673/how-to-copy-a-file-from-my-home-folder-to-usr/10681#10681) but issue still the same.

Hope i get some help. I am using ubuntu 18.04LTS.

Comment: Maybe your module is not signed, while kernel have restrict policy for unsigned modules?

Comment: @Alex So you are saying i may need to somehow remove the policy restrictions?

Comment: You should check https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/module-signing.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I had the same problem and this worked for me:

1. You need to disable Secure Boot using mokutil [use the first answer in this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)
2. Run the insmod command via sudo.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If `$ sudo insmod file_name.ko` fails with mentioned error, then do `dmesg | tail -1`

and it will give idea of what exactly went wrong while installing kernel-module.

In my case it was because another module was overlapping on same /sys/class location.

After doing `sudo rmmod <that_module.ko>` I was able to load my new kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

If your kernel is locally build and locally signed with a generated signature,you could sign the module using same keys.

```
<kernel source>/scripts/sign-file sha512 MOK.priv MOK.pem module.ko
```

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/module-signing.html,
https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface/blob/3267e4ea1f318bb9716d6742d79162de8277dea2/SIGNING.md

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure in `makefile` there is tab after all: and clean: not space
then save it and run command make
After that, insert the kernel by following command.
`$ sudo insmod file_name.ko`
Finally, display.
`$ dmesg | tail -1`

Comment: This response does not answer the question, though.