# insmod: ERROR could not insert module: Operation not permitted in WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: wsl-2, insmod

I followed the instructions [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_YnACEPmrM) to compile the Linux kernel for WSL with video drivers. The kernel is running and I do have access to `/dev/video0` which was the whole point.

I can also confirm that the correct kernel is running with `uname -a`, which gives the following output:

```bash
Linux DESKTOP-V575QHO 5.15.74.2-microsoft-standard-WSL2+ #1 SMP Wed Dec 7 14:57:03 CET 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I now installed `dkms` and used it to compile the [akvcam module (a virtual camera driver)](https://github.com/webcamoid/akvcam.git). Both `make` and `make dkms_install` exited successfully.

However, when I'm actually trying to install the module using `insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms/akvcam.ko` I get the following error:

```bash
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/5.15.74.2-microsoft-standard-WSL2+/updates/dkms/akvcam.ko: Operation not permitted
```

I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546126/insmod-error-could-not-insert-module-helloworld-ko-operation-not-permitted?rq=1) that this might be related to Secure Boot, but I don't really understand how this would translate to WSL2 and how this problem could be solved here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try turning off secure boot. It continues to exist after boot up, and it may very well be the problem. I don't know the exact details on how it could cause it. But it uses keys that persist after boot. It's so simple to try it. And secure boot isn't all it's cracked up to be. I always  turn it off.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how to turn off secure boot for WSL2? The resources I found seemed to only target "standard" linux installs, where I could enter the boot menu during startup of my computer. I also found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules) that recommended using `mokutil` and then running `sudo mokutil --disable-validation`, but that didn't work for me with WSL either.