# Could not insert the kernel module even with sudo

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am studying the Linux kernel device driver. I compiled the char device driver with kernel but while inserting with `insmod`, I am getting error as following,

```sh
$ sudo insmod sample-module.ko 
[sudo] password for sss: 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module sample-module.ko: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Most likely `dmesg` will give you more information about the problem. See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546126/insmod-error-could-not-insert-module-helloworld-ko-operation-not-permitted) and its answers.

Comment: i did not see anything in dmesg. is it because of bios security of the laptop?

Comment: `-EPERM` most likely due to missing module signatire if you are trying on the existing distro provided kernel.